# After pressing record button recording starts and instantly stops in Android App

Tags: java, android

I am making my first Android App where I need to take a video of 45 secs to calculate pulse from it.

Recording video is coded the simple way, using `startActivityForResult()`(something similar to [record video using intent](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Recording_and_Image_Capture_using_Camera_Intents_-_An_Android_Studio_Example)). The activity to record video successfully starts but when the record button is pressed recording starts and instantly stops. I have no clue as to why. Logcat displays no error output with respect to the activity. Even, there is no mention of any of my source files in any info or error Logs in Logcat.

Here are my files

1. **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private Camera c;
    private CameraView cv1;
    private FrameLayout view_camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))) {
            this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture video_capture;

        Button button_symptoms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_symptoms);
        Button button_upload_signs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_upload_signs);
        Button button_measure_heart_rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_measure_heart_rate);
        Button button_measure_respiratory_rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_measure_respiratory_rate);

        cv1 = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), this);
        view_camera = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_camera);
        view_camera.addView(cv1);

        TextView finger_on_sensor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_finger_on_sensor);
        finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        finger_on_sensor.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg_view, MotionEvent arg_me) {
                finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                File file_video = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video_finger.mp4");
                final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
                Intent intent_record_video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 45);
                Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.cse535a1.provider", file_video);
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent_record_video, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(packageName, fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
                intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent_record_video, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                return false;
            }

        });

        button_symptoms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Loggin_symptoms.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        button_upload_signs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {

            }
        });

        button_measure_heart_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        button_measure_respiratory_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                SensorManager manager_sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
                Sensor sensor_accelerometer = manager_sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                manager_sensor.registerListener(MainActivity.this, sensor_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setCam(Camera arg_camera) {
        c = arg_camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg_event) {
        float x = arg_event.values[0];
        float y = arg_event.values[1];
        float z = arg_event.values[2];
        Log.i("ACCELEROMETER", String.valueOf(x) + ' ' + String.valueOf(y) + ' ' + String.valueOf(z));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg_sensor, int arg_accuracy) {

    }

    public Camera getcam() {
        Camera c = null;
        try { c = Camera.open(0); }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        c.unlock();
//        if (c != null) {
//            c.stopPreview();
//            c.release();
//            c = null;
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        if (c != null) {
//            c.stopPreview();
//            c.release();
//            c = null;
//        }
//        cv1 = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), this);
//        view_camera.addView(cv1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (c != null) {
            c.stopPreview();
            c.release();
            c = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

2. **CameraView.java**

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder holder_surface;
    private Camera camera_selected;
    MainActivity act1;

    public CameraView(Context arg_context, MainActivity arg_activity) {
        super(arg_context);
//        camera_selected = arg_camera;
        act1 = arg_activity;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        holder_surface = getHolder();
        holder_surface.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        holder_surface.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg_holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
//            Log.i("CAMNULL", "CAM IS : " + String.valueOf(camera_selected == null));
            Camera c = null;
            try {
                c = Camera.open(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("CAMERA", "Camera not opened");
            }
            act1.setCam(c);
            camera_selected = c;
            camera_selected.setPreviewDisplay(arg_holder);
//            camera_selected.startPreview();
//            Log.i("Cam", "surface creator");
        } catch (IOException e) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
//        if (camera_selected != null) {
//            camera_selected.stopPreview();
//            camera_selected.release();
//            camera_selected = null;
//        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg_holder, int arg_format, int arg_width, int arg_height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (holder_surface.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera_selected.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera_selected.setPreviewDisplay(holder_surface);
            camera_selected.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
//            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

3. **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cse535a1">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CSE535A1">
        <activity android:name=".Loggin_symptoms"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.cse535a1.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <!-- ressource file to create -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I am attaching images for you convenience.**

Activity started and record button is pressed (i want to record a video for 45 secs).
[image: recording started when record button pressed]
The next instant recording stops
[image: reocrding stopped the next instant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File file_video = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video_finger.mp4");
final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
// StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
// StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
Intent intent_record_video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 45);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.cse535a1.provider", file_video);
// List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent_record_video, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
// for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
//     String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
//     getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(packageName, fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
// }
intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent_record_video, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

This code(in my MainActivity.java file) is similar to [videobasics](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics) on Android Developers. With my experience, I will say that it will work for API level 28 and not for API level 30, don't know about API 29.